# TypeScript class method as property

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use a method as a property in TypeScript?

Like, for example, in Python `@property` decorator

Comment: You mean, like a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) or [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)?

Comment: @CRice Yes it is exactly this, still learning 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an accessor property, like this:

```
class Example {
    get name(): string {
        return "Fred";
    }
}
```

[Example on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0A5ugC7QB2y6AFAJQBc0EJATgJbmHZ4G8ukBXFuWgAiAGL8AJqIDcPfAF8cy4AHtyzaJgC8FdAHc4iVBjrz1mtRgB0INYWroblJOlqzoAei9jJ6GSA)

That's an accessor property that only has a getter. You can also define a setter:

```
class Example {
    private _name: string = "";

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

(You don't have to store the value in a TypeScript-style private member, that's just an example.)

Technically, you can have an accessor with a setter and no getter (a write-only property).

Comment: It's more simple than I've imagined, very clear response, thank you